# Basic ODE story - tank with pumps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications

> Full tank has $500$ liter of water containing $0.2\%$ of salt. One pipe pumps clear water in ($100$ liters per minute) and the other gets the mixture from the tank ($100$ liters per minute too). Assume salt dissolves in water instantly. Find the function that describes the concentration of salt in a tank at any given time $t$.

---

I solved this easily:
$$
x(t + \Delta t)500L = 500Lx(t) + \Delta t \frac{100L}{min}(0 - x(t))\\
\frac{x(t + \Delta t)500L - 500L x(t)}{\Delta t} = -x(t) \frac{100L}{min}\\
x' = -\frac{1}{5}x \implies x(t) = e^{-0.2t}
$$

Now, lets spin the example a little:

> Our tank has 400 liter of water containing $0.5$% of salt. One pipe pumps the clear water in (10 liters per minute) and second one pumps the solution out (**20** liters per minute).

How to find the solution then? The answer should be $x(t) = \frac{(t-40)^2}{800}$.

**EDIT**: I'd appreciate the downvoter to tell me why they think the question is not well suited to the stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the same thing, only now the volume is also variable, so that for the "salt mass" = "salt concentration" times "volume" you get
$$
x(t+Δt)V(t+Δt)=x(t)V(t)-x(t)V_{out}Δt
\\
V(t+Δt)=V(t)+(V_{in}-V_{out})Δt
$$
so that applying the product rule of differentiation
$$
\dot x(t)V(t)+x(t)\dot V(t)=-x(t)V_{out}
\\
\dot V(t)=V_{in}-V_{out}
$$
where $V_{out}=20L/min$ and $V_{in}-V_{out}=-10L/min$. This gives directly $V(t)=400-10t$, $t$ in minutes.

So it remains to solve a nice linear ODE 
$$
(400-10t)\dot x(t)+10x(t)=0 \implies x(t)=C(400-10t).
$$
By the initial conditions $C=0.005/400=0.01/800$. As density and volume shrink linearly, their product, the total mass of salt in the tank, follow the quadratic law
$$
x(t)V(t)=\frac{(40-t)^2}{800}.
$$